# How to disable Alt+left click window dragging in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, xfce

I tried compizconfig-settings-manager and dconf-editor to change respectively Window Management>Move Window and org>gnome>desktop>wm>preferences>mouse-button-modifier to Super and Alt instead of Alt. Someone mentioned also, that there should be some Layout>Options in  Settings Manager>Windows but I got only things that on the image. Non of which has any option to change Alt+click behaviour:

View of settings menu:

[image: view of settings menu]

Please help if You know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question on [XFCE forums by vineel567](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=27320#p27320):

> Type `xfce4-settings-manager` in terminal and then click 'settings
>   editor'. Then to the left click xfwm4 channel then in the right pane
>   change the value of `easy_click` from `<alt>` to 'nothing'.

It of course works. Sorry for being stupid and not checking what DE I have before trying to change its settings.